# How to List App Services ( Webapp ) Runtimes?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a thousand app services in different subscriptions running on Microsoft Azure. I need to pull all the runtime version for each webapp.

I used this CLI Azure command to list the runtimes actually running in my subscriptions:

```
az webapp list-runtimes --subscription
```

But, I need to have the information for each webapp.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful if you could explain what you do get from that command (maybe share a sample?) and more specifically what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello @josephkibe,

Thanks for your comment

Yes of course this is Command PowerShell Thant can list the runtimes of all you app services in a subscription. Sample of what I get :{  "aspnet|V4.8",
  "aspnet|V3.5",
  "DOTNETCORE|2.1",
  "DOTNETCORE|3.1",
  "DOTNET|5.0",
  "node|10.6",
  "node|10.10",
  "node|10.14",
  "node|12-lts",
  "php|7.2",
  "php|7.3",
  "php|7.4",
  "python|3.6",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|7.0",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|8.0",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|9.0",}

I wanted to know if we can in Azure Extract the runtimes for each webapp

Answer (score 3):

This is more difficult than it should be given that not all properties are exposed by all CLI methods (or REST API calls), and some of the ones that are aren't populated. It is made even more complex by the fact that different properties are used for Windows and Linux hosts.

However it can be done using a combination of CLI commands. This PowerShell script will generate a JSON file for all the app services in a subscription, with their relevant runtimes and versions. Like this:

**Script:**

```
# Define a collection to hold the output
$runtimes = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]@()

# Get subscription id
Write-Progress "Fetching subscription id"
$sub = (az account show --query id -o tsv)

# Get all resource groups in the subscription
Write-Progress "Searching for resource groups"
$groups = (az group list --query "[].name" -o tsv)

# Set counter for group progress
$groupCounter = 1;

# Loop through each resource group to find all the web apps in it
foreach($group in $groups) {

    # Find web apps in the specified group
    Write-Progress "Searching for web apps in resource group $group" -PercentComplete (($groupCounter / $groups.Count) * 100)
    $apps =(az webapp list -g $group --query "[?kind=='app' || kind=='app,linux'].name" -o tsv)

    # Iterate the web apps
    foreach($app in $apps) {

        # Query the web app for versions
        Write-Progress "Querying web app $app"
        $appConfig = (az webapp show -n $app -g $group --query "{java:siteConfig.javaversion,netFramework:siteConfig.netFrameworkVersion,php:siteConfig.phpVersion,python:siteConfig.pythonVersion,linux:siteConfig.linuxFxVersion}") | ConvertFrom-Json

        # Define an output object
        $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
            group = $group
            name = $app
            host = $null
            runtime = $null
            version = $null
        }

        # Determine which type of app service it is and get the values accordingly
        if($appConfig.linux -eq "") {

            # Windows platform
            $output.host = "windows"

            # Query the app config to get the metadata for the current stack
            $uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$app/config/metadata/list?api-version=2020-10-01"
            $output.runtime = (az rest --method post --uri $uri --query "properties.CURRENT_STACK" -o tsv)

            # Determine the version of the relevant stack
            $output.version = switch($output.runtime) {
                "dotnet" {$appConfig.netFramework}
                "dotnetcore" {$null}
                "python" {$appConfig.python}
                "php" {$appConfig.php}
                "java" {$appConfig.java}
                default {$null}    
            }        

        } else {

            # Linux platform
            $output.host = "linux"

            # Split out the stack from the version
            $output.runtime = $appConfig.linux.split("|")[0]
            $output.version = $appConfig.linux.split("|")[1]

        }

        $runtimes.Add($output)
    }

    $groupCounter = $groupCounter + 1
}

# Convert the collection to JSON and write it out to a file
Write-Output $runtimes  | ConvertTo-Json > "webapp-runtimes-$sub.json"
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "group": "sample-group",
    "name": "sample-ruby-app",
    "host": "linux",
    "runtime": "RUBY",
    "version": "2.6"
  },
  {
    "group": "php-group",
    "name": "sample-php-app",
    "host": "windows",
    "runtime": "php",
    "version": "7.3"
  },
  {
    "group": "linux-apps",
    "name": "sample-node-app",
    "host": "linux",
    "runtime": "NODE",
    "version": "14-lts"
  },
  {
    "group": "linux-apps",
    "name": "sample-dotnetcore-app",
    "host": "linux",
    "runtime": "DOTNETCORE",
    "version": "3.1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to get runtime versions for each app services in multiple subscriptions:

- Assuming that you have all the subscriptions within same account
- Assuming that you have Windows WebApps

Code:

```
    $subscriptions = az account list | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($s in $subscriptions) {
      az account set -s $s.name
      $webapps = az resource list --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites' | ConvertFrom-Json
      foreach ($w in $webapps) {
        $config =  az webapp config show --name $w.name --resource-group $w.resourcegroup | ConvertFrom-Json
        $res = $config.name + ""
        $res += $config.windowsFxVersion
        $res >> file.txt
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @AndriyBilous, 

Thanks you , I have all the the subscriptions in a same account , and I have Windows WebApps. Actually it's list only the web apps without the runtime version on the txt file